# Android WiFi Network Switching Not Working - Need some ideas

Tags: android

I see that others are running into this problem and am hoping someone could give me a hand with some suggestions.

I have an app that runs on company devices, and is typically connected to a WiFi hotspot in a vehicle.  However that hotspot has a limited data plan to keep costs down.

When the vehicle gets back to the office I was forcing it onto the office network which is not metered using:

```
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId,true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

But this is broken now in Android 10 - and all of our new tablets are coming with Android 10.

I have played with the Suggested and Specified networks - however these don't seem to force the device to switch very well - and prompt the user to switch - which our vehicle drivers may or may not switch the setting.

Anyone know if there is a way to just force the WiFi to change?

I'm trying to switch to a network that is already configured in the device - it's not an "unknown" network to the device.  So it poses no security risk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this has been deprecated in the latest versions of Android.
so it's not possible to force the device over if you're targeting the latest SDK